# Why not to include a .js file containing Express.js code into an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-services, express

Not an unsolved problem, but rather a technical question, which I hope is valuable enough to ask.

As a beginner web developer, I attempted to give a variable from a .js file to an .html file, to display a variable from the former on-screen - I desired to do so by the `<script src=...` parameter. The .js file I wanted to include in the .html is the one that contains the code, which creates the HTTP server (as of yet a simple one) and loads the .html file.

I was told that it is a bad idea, and I should use JSON objects instead. THe problem is therefore solved, but I'm interested: why was it a bad idea to include the script of Express.js within the HTML file?

Comment: Because you'll get errors?

Comment: Express needs node. Because it's javascript doesn't mean it needs nothing more than a JS engine. Some javascript needs a browser (and frequently a DOM), some others have other needs.

Comment: @Andy I didn't, yet I have to admit that displaying variables did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express.js is Node.js web application framework. Lets simply call it backend javascript, which means it's designed to be run not in browser, but as part of Node.js application.

Just FYI:

There is a way to 'run' some Node modules in browser. There is tool called [browserify](http://browserify.org) .

Here what they are saying on their web site:

> Use **many** of the tens of thousands of modules on NPM in the browser

I'm afraid that Express.js is not one of those **'many'** modules.